# How do I change a button, onclick, in ActionScript? Show/hide?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Using ActionScript 2.0, how do I show or hide a button onclick? I am making a simple mp3 player, and would like my pause button to change to a play button when clicked, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
play_btn.onRelease = function () {
    // do something here.. like play mp3
    play_btn._visible = false;
    pause_btn._visible = true;
}

pause_btn.onRelease = function () {
    // do something here.. like pause mp3
    play_btn._visible = true;
    pause_btn._visible = false;
}
```

please be remember to give the instance name of play_btn and pause_btn to the play and pause buttons

Answer (score -1):

What I'm doing is instead creating a MovieClip and just simulating click, etc, with 4 different keyframes